# The requested URL / was not found on this server. in Wamp 3.1.0

Tags: apache, wampserver

I know there are similar questions about this but non of them resolve my problem.

I already used virtual host and it was running before until this morning this error occurred when I tried to access this link `http://www.notification.test/`

I have this kind of error.

> Not Found
>   The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) Server at www.notification.test Port 80

I have this in my hosts `127.0.0.1       www.notification.test`
and this is my setup in `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf\extra`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp64/www/notification/public
    ServerName www.notification.test
        <Directory C:/wamp64/www/notification/public>
            Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I just add the directory as what suggested from another post but didn't work.

My Wamp version is 3.1.0 running in 64 bit windows7 OS and the Apache is 2.4.47.

Need some help guys and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically its just a missing `/` see the `<Directory.....` parameter.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName notification.test
    ServerAlias www.notification.test
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/notification/public"
        <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/notification/public/">
            Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you HOSTS file should look like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 notification.test

::1 localhost
::1 notification.test
```

> Note:
>
> `Require all granted` is a bit unnecessary if you are just using other PC's in your own network. Instead use  `Require ip 192.168.0` for example, to allow any ip in your local network access but nothing outside your own network.

Comment: Still not working.... I can't even access the localhost... `http://locahost/phpmyadmin`.